# Create a Tkinter interfac with a button linked to a google places consult function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-requests, google-places-api, google-places

I wrote this code. It is working perfectly to obtain google-maps-api information to a structured CSV file:

```
def getPlaces(location,radius,i,j,k):
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+location+"&radius="+radius
    r = requests.get(url+"&types="+"establishment"+"&key="+API)
    response = r.json()
    results = []
    for result in response['results']:
        results.append(result)
    if len(results)<20:
        print('next type')
    return results
```

It should return a json structure:

> [{'geometry': {'location': {'lat': -1.526394, 'lng': -78.001286},
>   'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': -1.525045019708498,
>        'lng': -77.99993701970848},
>       'southwest': {'lat': -1.527742980291502, 'lng': -78.0026349802915}}},   'icon': 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png',
>   'id': '69e54af1e371137add1acca484b0fc7845184b1f',   'name':
>   'zoorefugio tarqui',   'opening_hours': {'open_now': True,
>   'weekday_text': []},   'photos': [{'height': 2592,
>       'html_attributions': ['[Franklin
>   Guaman](https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110206374169507916838/photos)'],
>       'photo_reference': 'CmRaAAAAWBe-CXcL8f52LopjP_nvS1BvtIrdhK5-XvYwG2oA9tS2oh3dzuyYlVIg_3z72mhf2NZ7Sv2S38UDm8J5lZkiDtC8hTZsLT9phKOA54i_W-DcuZQVnESGvHAizXRV4t1xEhAEx9KPnD5vjORlqLdVtrJEGhQ6YnBLp1P0GITIr8fEUB6a5WducA',
>       'width': 4608}],   'place_id': 'ChIJRePuE4re05ERVpc1cgpIogQ',   'rating': 4.5,   'reference':
>   'CmRRAAAA0MBgQLzubtDJGAJGZDW7wuZFujGVq6bNQNAvsMj5mQOVV9mNfmxKxlACFuC1UL8exB2AEtj63yiraasnbAHFf7TmBSd7bLZ1b_HFd2H6Z5JbJ5sIAS1CA3dQ-lWsMAIAEhBVgsIvcMM2aPdCUU6739lzGhT7o9nZun5tM0klSzyQf8nNhkGDzg',
>   'scope': 'GOOGLE',   'types': ['zoo',    'bar',    'restaurant',
>   'food',    'point_of_interest',    'establishment'],   'vicinity':
>   'Parroquia Tarqui, 160150 Puyo, Ecuador, Puyo'}]

The next code will transform that json into a frame and save it as a CSV in to a file:

```
def placesCsv(location,radius,i,j,k):
    places_jn=json_normalize(getPlaces(location,radius,i,j,k))
    s = places_jn.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['types']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
    s.name = 'types'
    places_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','types'], keep='first', inplace=True)
    places_df.to_csv('google_places'+str(location)+'.csv')
```

I obtain these results, and they are saved as a csv in the set file:

```
> next type 
> next type amusement_park API: 20
> 2 20 2  
> next type aquarium API: 20
> 2 20 3  
> Did not find results for the type aquarium 
> next type art_gallery API: 20
> 2 20 4  
> Did not find results for the type art_gallery 
> this was the final type
```

As you see, it does not return the first two types airport and accounting, because it did not find any of them. Then it did not find any art_gallery, that is why it returns "Did not find results for the type art_gallery".

Now, I am trying to create a Tkinter interface to make the API consult like:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
def get_entry_fields():
   lat=e1.get()
   lng=e2.get()
   latlng=str(lat)+','+str(lng)

def radius():
    radius=str(e3.get())

def look():
    print("Single Click, Button-l") 
    places=placesCsv(location=str(get_entry_fields()),
                     radius=str(radius()),
                     i=0,
                     j=10,
                     k=0)

def quit():                           
    print("Right Click, so let's stop") 
    widget.destroy

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="lat").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="lng").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="radius").grid(row=2)

e1=Entry(master)
e2=Entry(master)
e3=Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.destroy).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=look).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop( )
```

When I run the function through the interface with the same lat, lng and radius and the output looks like:

```
> Single Click, Button-l
> next type
> next type amusement_park10
> 0 10 2
> next type aquarium10
> 0 10 3
> next type art_gallery10
> 0 10 4
> this was the final type
```

As you see, it does not return the first two types ariport and accounting, because it did not find any of them. It found other places, but the list "results" has a length zero. Then the json file does not have any list of types. So I get this error:

```
> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\NA401134\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
> line 1699, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)   File "<ipython-input-50-8e3a3f48613d>", line 32, in look
>     k=0)   File "<ipython-input-42-4681f83b6314>", line 5, in placesCsv
>     places_df=places_jn.drop('types', axis=1).join(s)   File "C:\Users\NA401134\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
> line 2161, in drop
>     new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)   File >"C:\Users\NA401134\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site->packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
> line 3624, in drop
>     labels[mask]) ValueError: labels ['types'] not contained in axis
```

As you see I can't transform json to frame because there are not results in types when the consult is made through the interface.

Comment: use button `{}` to format error messages - they will be better formated.

Comment: BTW: `widget.destroy()` in `quit()` needs `()` at the end.

Comment: you could put all functions at the beginning - before `master = Tk()` - to make code more readable.

Comment: Your Tkinter Interface code looks good, make sure you're accounting for entry fields may be empty before `get`.

Comment: use `print()` and `print(type(...))` in `placesCsv` to see what values you get at start.

Comment: it gets a json that is normalized into frame later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works as:

```
def get_entry_fields(lat,lng):
   latlng=str(lat)+','+str(lng)
   return(latlng)


def look():
    print("Single Click, Button-l") 
    places=PlacesCsv(
            location=get_entry_fields(
                    lat=e1.get(),
                    lng=e2.get()
                    ),
                    radius=str(
                            e3.get()
                            ),
                     i=0,
                     j=100,
                     k=0)

def quit():                           
    print("Right Click, so let's stop") 
    widget.destroy()

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="lat").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="lng").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="radius").grid(row=2)

e1=Entry(master)
e2=Entry(master)
e3=Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.destroy).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=look).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop( )
```